# EF Code first Composite Key link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1, composite-key

As I'm trying to change code first app to fit a multi tenancy demads, I basically added additional key column to all tables(and creating composite primary key):

```
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)] 
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }


public class Worker
{
     [Key, Column(Order = 0)] 
    public  int WorkerID{ get; set; }
     [Key, Column(Order = 1)] 
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity SomeActivity { get; set; }

}

public class Activity
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)] 
    public int ActivityID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)] 
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Desc.")]
    public virtual string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

When EF tries to generate database I get the error :

*Foreign key constraint 'Activity_ActActivityt' from table Worker(CompanyID, ActivityId) to table Activity (ActivityID, CompanyID):: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign key association on the conceptual side.*

Could you show me how to map these two tables, taking in account that For each user an activity is to be chosen.

Thanks,
tihi

Comment: Incidentally, I had this exact issue earlier on this afternoon. I'm not 100% certain (still haven't fixed the issue -- I stopped working on it) but I think you may need to include a navigation property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you will have to set the foreign key mappings explicitly using data annotations (instead of relying on the conventions), however I am not entirely sure if this will work since you have overlap of a FK with a PK. In theory it should, though :)

```
public class Worker
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)] 
    public  int WorkerID{ get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)] 
    [ForeignKey("SomeActivity")]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SomeActivity")]
    public virtual int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity SomeActivity { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Hello Justin, and thanks for the hint. It did solve my initial issue. However, right away new issues popped up. So i think I'll drop CompanyId as a key and simply use it as a 'filter' field and see how that works. :)

Comment: Just as an aside, you could try using the fluent api as it has more robustness as to what you can configure. It ultimately creates the attributes in the background (for the most part), so I am not sure if it would help or not. As long as you have working code, I am happy, though :)